# convert table data into PDF with JSPDF and AutoTable

Tags: jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to generate PDF file from HTML table using JSPDF and AutoTable.
A html table is given below:

```
<table id="table" style="display:none;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>sl</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>jkl</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>pqr</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My question: Is there any option to hide the header column named "`Sl`" when converting the table data into the PDF file?

Fiddle is here :
https://jsfiddle.net/tbz8p79j/7/

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the first column can be accomplished by simply setting it's width to zero:

```
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
  columnStyles: {0: {columnWidth: 0}}
});
```

You can also play with for example the drawCell hook similar to the colspan and rowspan example in the repo.

Comment: what to do if I want to hide more than one column.. can you please provide me an example

Comment: `columnStyles: {0: {columnWidth: 0}, 1: {columnWidth: 0}}`